Is there an option in vite.config.ts to include all types in index.d.ts when building with Vite bundler?
I published a custom hook package using Vite bundler, but in the dist folder, the index.d.ts does not contain type declarations for functions, causing errors when trying to import types.
The file structure of my package includes index.ts and useInfiniteScroll.ts within the src folder. index.ts exports useInfiniteScroll.ts.
Ideally, only index.ts and index.d.ts should be built, but a useInfiniteScroll.d.ts file keeps appearing. Consequently, when trying to find types in index.d.ts from where it's used, it throws errors indicating missing types.
Currently, the error seems related to exports rather than types, but I'm unsure where to begin or what needs to be fixed. I'll share my tsconfig.json, vite.config.ts, and the specific error message.
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), dts(), commonjs()],
  cacheDir: './.vite',
  resolve: {
    alias: { find: '@', replacement: '/src' },
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    sourcemap: false,
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: './src/index.ts',
      output: {
        format: 'esm',
        entryFileNames: 'index.js',
      },
    },
    outDir: './dist',
    assetsDir: '',
  },
})

//tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"],
}

Error msg when using the package in my projects.

_*** my packages name *** __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function
TypeError: _*** my packages name ***__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function

I've tried adding dts() inside plugins in vite.config.ts and thoroughly checked Vite's official build documentation multiple times, but I couldn't find a solution.
I also experimented with different export methods, thinking it might be an export issue, but that didn't work either.
No matter how many times I modify it, I keep encountering the same error.
Just in case, let me also share the index.ts file inside src.
Attempt 1
export { useInfiniteScroll } from './useInfiniteScroll'

Attempt 2
import { useInfiniteScroll } from './useInfiniteScroll'

export { useInfiniteScroll }

